# Redirect Jenkins and Sonatype Nexus on port 80

Tags: jenkins, port, nexus

I have configured Jenkins(my.example.com:8080/jenkins) and Nexus (my.example.com:8081/nexus). Both are installed on single server i.e CentOS 6.6 x64. To start Jenkins I use command "service jenkins start" and for nexus I use "service nexus start". Just to mention that I did't deployed both of them on tomcat. I just want to get rid of using port number. Means to say for Jenkins url must be "my.example.com/jenkins" and for nexus "my.example.com/nexus". Could you please suggest me on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accomplished with nginx.
Just go to : nginx: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    `location ~ /jenkins {

         return 301 my.example.com:8080/jenkins;

    }

    location ~ /nexus {

         return 301 my.example.com:8081/nexus;

    }`

Answer (score 0):

Install an Apache HTTP server which gets requests for my.example.com and communicates to ports for each link... It is a bit tricky to setup this environment, if you do not have enough experiment with http servers it will take a lot of time...